# Exclude elements from mapping

Tags: list-manipulation

I have had this problem way too often and still have not found a solution, yet. 
One acually used code is:`

```
VectorQuantity[perms_List, dim_Integer] :=
 Module[
  {elementList := Range[1, dim],
   collectionList := {},
   v = {}},
  If[collectionList = Union[collectionList, v]; 
     MemberQ[collectionList, #],
     Unevaluated[Sequence[]],
     v = PermutationReplace[#, perms]] & /@ elementList]
```

perms is a list of cycles. During the mapping over `elementList` I find elements over which I do not want to map anymore. Right now, they are put into a list, and I use `If` and `MemberQ`. I know that there are more issues with the code like the `;` within the condition, but those do not matter to me, right now. What I am asking for is whether there is a good way to control the part behind the `/@`

I apologize for unclearness in the unedited question. I am rather new to Mathematica, and my English is terrible ;)

Comment: MapAt[f, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {{2}, {5}}] (*{1, f[2], 3, 4, f[5]}*) ??

Comment: I'm sorry. I have edited the question. Please inform me, if it is still unclear.

Comment: I must admit I still have trouble understanding this.  Assuming your code works as you intend what is wrong with using `MemberQ` and then effectively dropping the element with `Unevaluated[Sequence[]]`? (Which by the way you can replace with `## &[]`.)  Conceptually how else would you do this?

Comment: The problem here is that this code will be performed for very huge dim. But in general, I am really curious about whether there is a way to implement this more efficiently. Now, a friend of mine has replaced it with a "reap-nestwhile-saw"-function which is actually better. (I do not have the code here, right now. If you want, I can add it soon)

Answer (score 2):

### Answer rewritten after changes to question

[See the edit history for the previous version.]

As I understand the revised example code, and I'm not sure if this is correct or even if it actually has any utility, the function $f$ should be mapped such that the result
$y_i = f(x_i)$
is not calculated if the *argument* $x_i$ appears in the prior *results*,
$y_1, y_2, ... y_{i-1}$.

I think the following is a function that generalises this:

```
strangelyMap[f_, elementList_List] := Block[
  {collectionList = {f[First[elementList]]}, g},
  g[x_] := (collectionList = Join[collectionList, {f[x]}]) /; ! MemberQ[collectionList, x];
  g /@ Rest[elementList];
  collectionList]
```

(Replace `Join` by `Union` if you require sorted results with no repeats.)

A somewhat contrived example:

```
strangelyMap[Mod[#, 10] &, Reverse[Range[20]]]
```

> {0, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0}

And the way to use it with the incomplete example in the question:

```
strangelyMap[PermutationReplace[#, perms] &, Range[dim]]
```

Comment: That appears to be about what I had in mind. Bu I see, I had to show an actual example^^ Nevertheless, thank you! :)

Comment: (after your edit)
That function does exactly what I meant. But my actual question is:
Is there a more efficient way to implement strangelyMap?

Still, thank you very much! :)

Comment: @Fred As you said "I have had this problem way too often" I thought a generalisation would be helpful. I'm not sure there can be a better method unless you know the results in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
Take[Range[50],25]
```

???????????????????????????????